# How to navigate in Gradle API documentation?

Tags: groovy, gradle

This could be a unusual question. I have a problem with navigating in gradle groovy api doc. For example see following code,

```
uploadArchives {
repositories {
    ivy {
        credentials {
            username "username"
            password "pw"
        }
    url "http://repo.mycompany.com"
    }
}
}
```

In above code how can i find what goes into "credentials" closure in api documentaion ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite new to Gradle myself, but this is what I would do:

1. Start from [`Project`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html) as the build script is always executed against a `Project` instance
2. Look for [`repositories { }`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project%3arepositories%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)
3. It mentions `RepositoryHandler`, so look for [`ivy { }`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.RepositoryHandler%3aivy%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) there
4. `ivy()` returns a [`IvyArtifactRepository`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.IvyArtifactRepository.html), so I guess the closure will be executed against that
5. However there is no `credentials { }` defined on [`IvyArtifactRepository`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.IvyArtifactRepository.html)
6. Jump to [its API doc](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/IvyArtifactRepository.html) to check its superclasses (link on the top of the page)
7. You can see there that `credentials` is defined on [`AuthenticationSupported`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/AuthenticationSupported.html#credentials%28groovy.lang.Closure%29)
8. [`PasswordCredentials`](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/repositories/PasswordCredentials.html) is mentioned there, and finally you see that it only has `username` and `password` properties

It's not always very intuitive, and I miss code completion a lot, but once you get the hang of it, it becomes easier to find your way through the documentation.